# Properties of tournament (degrees sums)

Tags: graph-theory

In an oriented multigraph $G=(X, U)$ we have: $$\sum_{x \in X} d^+ (x)=\sum_{x \in X} d^- (x),$$ where $d(x)=d^+(x)+d^-(x)$ denote the degree order of vertex $x$ ($d^+(x)$ and $d^-(x)$ denotes the external degree and the internal degree, respectively, of vertex $x$).

I need to show that if $G$ is a tournament then the following equality holds
$$\sum_{x \in X} (d^+ (x))^2=\sum_{x \in X} (d^- (x))^2.$$

We say that $G=(X,U)$ is a tournament when $G$ is a digraph resulting from the orientation of complete graphs, $n\geq 2$ vertices.

> Can anyone give me some help with this proof?

Comment: $(d^+)^2-(d^-)^2=(d^++d^-)(d^+-d^-)=(n-1)(d^+-d^-)$.

Comment: $$\sum_{x\in X}\binom{d^+(x)}2=\sum_{x\in X}\binom{d^-(x)}2$$ because both sums count the number of non-cyclic triangles in the tournament.

Comment: Have the comments helped?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you want to write up a solution and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, a tournament $G=(X,U)$ is a digraph resulting from the orientation of complete graphs, $n\geq 2$ vertices. Therefore, we have that $d(x)=d^+ (x)+d^- (x)=n-1$, for all $x\in X$.

> Note that if we have $\displaystyle\sum_{x\in X} (d^+ (x))^2-\sum_{x\in X} (d^- (x))^2=0$ the second equality is valid.

Let us see that in fact the second equality is verified
\begin{eqnarray*}
\displaystyle\sum_{x\in X} (d^+ (x))^2-\sum_{x\in X} (d^- (x))^2 &=&  \sum_{x\in X}[(d^+ (x))^2-(d^- (x))^2]\\
&=& \sum_{x\in X}\left[(d^+ (x)-d^- (x))(d^+ (x)+d^- (x))\right]\\
&=&  \sum_{x\in X}\left[(d^+ (x)-d^- (x))(n-1)\right]\\
&=& (n-1) \sum_{x\in X}\left[d^+ (x)-d^- (x)\right]\\
&=& (n-1) \left[\sum_{x\in X} d^+ (x)- \sum_{x\in X} d^- (x)\right]\\
&=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
We achieved the last equality using the first equality. Thus concluding that if $ G $ is a tournament, the second equality is valid.

Comment: Good. Well done.